# no http packet received after connection establishment

Tags: http, tcp, server

I have two servers with different ips, one is the ip that clients know and the other is private.

all packets directed to the first server gets redirected to the second locally by the network switch.

as you can see in the logs by wireshark there is no http packet arriving from client, all is continuation or non-http:

```
 15  29.352916 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   TCP 78 49975 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=4380 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=1 TSval=2098464254 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
 16  29.352970   10.0.0.100 -> 172.17.251.32 TCP 74 http > 49975 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1571906898 TSecr=2098464254 WS=256
 17  29.354856 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   TCP 66 49975 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=4380 Len=0 TSval=2098464257 TSecr=1571906898
 18  29.355093 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   HTTP 220 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
 19  29.355126   10.0.0.100 -> 172.17.251.32 TCP 66 http > 49975 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=155 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=1571906898 TSecr=2098464257
 20  29.355231   10.0.0.100 -> 172.17.251.32 HTTP 247 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
 21  29.355291   10.0.0.100 -> 172.17.251.32 TCP 66 http > 49975 [FIN, ACK] Seq=182 Ack=155 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=1571906898 TSecr=2098464257
 22  29.356955 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   TCP 66 49975 > http [ACK] Seq=155 Ack=183 Win=4561 Len=0 TSval=2098464259 TSecr=1571906898
 23  29.357405 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   HTTP 73 Continuation or non-HTTP traffic
 24  29.357424 172.17.251.32 -> 10.0.0.100   TCP 66 49975 > http [FIN, ACK] Seq=162 Ack=183 Win=4561 Len=0 TSval=2098464259 TSecr=1571906898
 25  29.357434   10.0.0.100 -> 172.17.251.32 TCP 66 http > 49975 [ACK] Seq=183 Ack=163 Win=30208 Len=0 TSval=1571906899 TSecr=2098464259
```

my guess is that there is a problem with redirection or some firewall problem.

what is the problem?

Comment: maybe something is blocking all packets that are not handshake packets.  Impossible to say as your firewall is a black box to us

Comment: @Vorsprung you are right but i have no access to those parts, all i can do is to make sure that the problem is not at my side and then blame others :)